# Is Perl slower when compiled with DDEBUGGING?

Tags: perl, debugging, compilation

According to this slide from [Supercharging Perl - Daina Pettit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV5Zv3zc3o8),

[image]

It reads,

> Avoid versions of `perl` compiled with threading or `DDEBUGGING` unless you know you need them.

I know most distros compile Perl with threading, but my Perl on Debian (as observed with `perl -V`_ is compiled with `-DDEBUGGING=-g` does this slow it down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Perl with debugging enabled is slower.](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/d316519608a8c33b67672f84c9c68eb6e85e6987/INSTALL#L1083),

> Note that a perl built with `-DDEBUGGING` will be much bigger and will run much, much more slowly than a standard perl.

However, `-DDEBUGGING=-g` does not enable debugging:

> As a convenience, debugging code (`-DDEBUGGING`) and debugging symbols (`-g`) can be enabled jointly or separately using a Configure switch, also (somewhat confusingly) named `-DDEBUGGING`.  For a more eye appealing call, `-DEBUGGING` is defined to be an alias for `-DDEBUGGING`. For both, the `-U` calls are also supported, in order to be able to overrule the hints or Policy.sh settings.

and [also documented](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/INSTALL):

> Configure `-DEBUGGING=-g`
>
> **Adds `-g` to optimize, but does not set `-DDEBUGGING`.** (Note:  Your system may actually require something like `cc -g2`. Check your man pages for cc(1) and also any hint file for your system.)

---

You can test status with: `perl -D`, if you see the following you do not have `-DDEBUGGING`,

> Recompile perl with `-DDEBUGGING` to use `-D` switch (did you mean -d ?)